# Angular Error Parsing ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I have an ng-show on a div in index.html which determines which header to display based on user-clearances. These clearances are stored in $scope.user.clearance as an array of clearance objects. $scope.user.clearance is structured as follows:

```
[
    {
       'clearance':string
    }
]
```

The directive causing the parse error is:

```
<div ng-show = "user.clearance &&
        user.clearance.filter(function(e) { return e['clearance'] === 'SUPERADMIN'; }).length > 0" 
        ng-include="'/partials/components/superadmin-header.html'">
</div>
```

The expression:

```
user.clearance && user.clearance.filter(function(e) { 
     return e['clearance'] === 'SUPERADMIN'; 
}).length > 0
```

Works just fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6frqzwee/2/

Any idea why angular is having difficulty with this?

Comment: you can't declare functions inside the `ng-show` directive. why not make your own directive to make the HTML shorter and have this be an easy to call item? Or create a scope function that checks this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ng-show` directive put [**`$watch` on the `expression` which you provide on `ng-show` attribute**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L165). If you pass expression as `string`, it evaluates them with current scope, but as you are passing function with an attribute will throw an `$parse` error.

Better to make it working you could have angular filter `|` which will give you the expected result and will not throw any error while parsing an HTML

```
<div ng-show ="user.clearance &&
    (user.clearance | filter: {clearance: 'SUPERADMIN' }).length > 0" 
    ng-include="'/partials/components/superadmin-header.html'">
```

As in above syntax `(user.clearance | filter: {clearance: 'SUPERADMIN' })` will evaluated with a scope and it will return array of matched element which has `clearance` property value with `SUPERADMIN`.